# Symfony2: Load bundles from other directory

Tags: symfony

My current project will be cms-like, and I contemplate about a plugin system.
My problem: Like many other cms', I wanna have a `plugins/` directory in the root, just to simplify it for the user. A custom script in the AppKernel will then load all the plugins/bundles form this directory. But I don't have even the slightest clue how to load bundles from other directorys. Does somebody here have experience in this situation?

King regards, hice3000.

Comment: Not sure this is a good practice

Comment: Think it the other way: symfony comes by default with composer to manage bundles. Y U NO USE IT? :)

Comment: Who does not use Composer? ;) But this is not the best way for a plugin system, users should only have to drag-and-drop a direcroty/bundel/plugin/whatever to a `plugin` directory. If somebody has another idea, **as simple as this**, please tell me.

Comment: Probably your best change is to look at drupal 8. It will probably give you an idea since it is a cms based on symfony2 and it has a plugin system.

Comment: Good idea, will take a look at it.

Comment: or take a look at Symfony CMF, if you want to stick using the Symfony framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like your problem is solved. But to answer your question, as that can help other people.

Loading bundles is just making sure the bundle class can be autoloaded. By default, Composer can load classes from the packages it installs. The Symfony Standard Edition configures the Composer autoloader to also load classes from `src` using this code in `composer.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    }
}
```

You can extend this to also load classes from the `plugin` directory:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "": "plugin/" }
    }
}
```

Read more in [their docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)